# javafx predicate fires only first time

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I have strange problem and i'm sure it is my code problem but unable to find out.

Problem:
I have a javafx TableView which is backed by a filteredlist which in turn backed by an observable list. My requirement is to filter the tableview data based on the input typed by the user in the textfield. So i have attached an invalidation listener on the textfield's textProperty and in that i'm trying to set the predicate of the filteredlist based on my business conditions which works fine.

See below code:

```
externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs) -> { 
//externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate(somePredicate);
String filterText = externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.getText().trim().toLowerCase();
externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate((ExternalTrade anExternalTrade) -> {
if(filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty() || filterText.equals(""))
return true;
if(anExternalTrade.getOid().toString().contains(filterText))
return true;
else 
if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeSourceOid().getExternalTradeSrcName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
return true;
else 
if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStatusOid().getExternalTradeStatusName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
return true;
else 
if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStateOid().getExternalTradeStateName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
return true;
return false;
});
});
```

Since i achieved my requirement i started concentrating on code refactoring. So planned to move the predicate logic to a separate predicate and move the predicate to another class so that i can reuse it.
Problem Started here.

See below code:

```
externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs) -> { 
externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate(somePredicate);
});

private Predicate<ExternalTrade> somePredicate = (ExternalTrade anExternalTrade) -> {
String filterText = externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.getText().trim().toLowerCase();

if(filterText.isEmpty() || filterText == null || filterText.equals(""))
            return true;
if(anExternalTrade.getOid().toString().contains(filterText))
       return true;
else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeSourceOid().getExternalTradeSrcName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
            return true;
else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStatusOid().getExternalTradeStatusName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
            return true;
        else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStateOid().getExternalTradeStateName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
            return true;
return false;
};
```

Now every time i type new text in the textfield my listener is getting executed but the predicate logic is called only for the first time. From the second time the predicate (somePredicate) is not getting called.

Please help me in this.  Also suggest whether my code is good or anyother better way to achieve this with better performance. bcoz i do see some code which uses binding saying the filteredProperty of the filteredlist is directly attached to the textfield's textProperty.

One More thing. the logic inside the predicate is to check the text is contained in any of the columns if so return the row. i have 20 columns. so do i need to write the if conditions for all the 20 columns or any other way. is for loop is the only way? or can i use .foreach and do something.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the filter won't recompute is that, from the `FilteredList`'s perspective, it doesn't change.

In pseudocode, `FilteredList` probably looks something like this:

```
public class FilteredList<T> {

    private ObjectProperty<Predicate<T>> predicate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private ObservableList<T> source ;

    public FilteredList<T>(ObservableList<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate) {

        this.source = source ;

        this.predicate.addListener((obs, oldPredicate, newPredicate) ->
            redoFilter());

        this.predicate.set(predicate);
    }

    // ...
}
```

i.e. it registers a `ChangeListener` with the predicate property and recomputes the filter if it changes. (In real life, it is probably considerably more complex than this, but that idea will be there.)

Meanwhile, `SimpleObjectProperty` does the following (again, this is pseudocode):

```
public class SimpleObjectProperty<T> implements Property<T> {

    private T value ;

    public void set(T value) {
        if (! Objects.equals(this.value, value)) {
            T oldValue = this.value ;
            this.value = value ; 
            notifyChangeListeners(oldValue, this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, `ChangeListener`s are only notified if the value *actually changes*.

In your example (second code block), whenever the text in your search field changes, you call

```
externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate(somePredicate);
```

with the exact same reference `somePredicate` every time. So when the property in the filtered list containing that predicate checks, it sees no change (exact same object...) and so the change listeners aren't fired, and consequently the filtered list doesn't know it has to update.

Effectively, you didn't change the predicate, you just changed the internal state of the existing predicate.

To fix, you can do:

```
private Predicate<ExternalTrade> createPredicate() {
    return (ExternalTrade anExternalTrade) -> {
        String filterText = externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.getText().trim().toLowerCase();

        if(filterText.isEmpty() || filterText == null || filterText.equals(""))
                    return true;
        if(anExternalTrade.getOid().toString().contains(filterText))
               return true;
        else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeSourceOid().getExternalTradeSrcName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
        else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStatusOid().getExternalTradeStatusName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
                else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStateOid().getExternalTradeStateName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
        return false;
    };

}
```

and

```
externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs) ->  
    externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate(createPredicate()));
```

or equivalently, create a class:

```
private static class TradeTableFilter implements Predicate<ExternalTrade> {

    private final String filterText ;

    TradeTableFilter(String filterText) {
        this.filterText = filterText ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(ExternalTrade anExternalTrade) {

        if(filterText.isEmpty() || filterText == null || filterText.equals(""))
                    return true;
        if(anExternalTrade.getOid().toString().contains(filterText))
               return true;
        else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeSourceOid().getExternalTradeSrcName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
        else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStatusOid().getExternalTradeStatusName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
                else if(anExternalTrade.getExternalTradeStateOid().getExternalTradeStateName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText))
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

and then of course do

```
externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs) ->  
    externalTradesFilteredList.setPredicate(new TradeTableFilter(externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.getText().trim().toLowerCase()));
```

For your other question (btw, you should not really combine multiple questions into one on this forum: it makes it difficult (or impossible) for other users to find existing answers to the same problems), there's no really easy fix.

You could create a list of the properties in your model as `Function<ExternalTrade, String>`:

```
private final List<Function<ExternalTrade, String>> tradeProperties = Arrays.asList(
    t -> t.getOid().toString(),
    t -> t.getExternalTradeSourceOid().getExternalTradeSrcName().toLowerCase(),
    t -> t.getExternalTradeStatusOid().getExternalTradeStatusName().toLowerCase(),
    t -> t.getExternalTradeStateOid().getExternalTradeStateName().toLowerCase()
);
```

and then

```
private Predicate<ExternalTrade> createPredicate() {
    return (ExternalTrade anExternalTrade) -> {
        String filterText = externalTradeTableViewDataFilterTextField.getText().trim().toLowerCase();
        return filterText == null ||
               filterText.isEmpty() ||
               tradeProperties().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.apply(anExternalTrade).contains(filterText));
    };
}
```

Depending on your model class and how you have the table set up, you might be able to map to `ObservableValue`s instead of `String`s in the list of functions, and then you could potentially reuse that list to create the columns in a loop too. But I don't know enough about your setup to know if that's possible.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't apply n check ur solution but it makes sense. Let me try that. And also sorry for putting multiple question. I'll correct myself from now.

Comment: Hey, I am trying ur solution. First Problem Solved. 2nd Problem. looping thru all columns, i am unable to say  tradeProperties().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.contains(filterText)); where p.contains is not working. I am unable to call the contains methods on p which is a predicate.

Comment: Thanks James. It Worked. Thanks a lot. Do u mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801302/design-to-keep-helper-methods-in-javafx-project