# design to keep helper methods in javafx project

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx, java-8

This may be more of design choice and I thought "why to reinvent the wheel". Someone might have required this already.

(I don't want to go for any third party framework since mine is a small project. I am using Adam Bein's `afterburner.fx` already). I am implementing a standalone application in javafx. I am very much interested in following MVC/MVP/MVVM. Since javafx allows me to separate the UI using fxml, I achieved most of my UI design through fxml. But there I stuck with some problems.

## My Structure

- TradeView.fxml (all my UI design goes here)
- `TradeController` (all my UI event handling (also some business logic) goes here)
- `Trade` (entity class)

Now I have a JavaFX `TableView` in my `fxml`. All `TableColumn`s are  defined in the `fxml` itself.  The values which I want to bind to my columns are achieved through `PropertyValueFactory` if it is a direct property in my entity class.

```
TableView<Trade> myTableView;
```

eg:

```xml
<TableColumn fx:id="tradeOidTableColumn" prefWidth="130.0" text="Trade Oid">
    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="oid"/></cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

But I want to show commodity short name in one column where `Commodity` is another entity in relationship with my `Trade` entity. So I can use

```
myTradeEntity.commodity().commodityShortName();
```

to get the value, which works perfectly. But you guys know I cannot do this though `fxml`. It doesn't support nested binding.

Not possible

```xml
<cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="commodity.commodityShortName"/></cellValueFactory>
```

So I am forced to use a cell value factory. I defined a class `CommodityCellValueFactory` and bind it.
eg:

```xml
<TableColumn fx:id="commodityTableColumn" prefWidth="220.0" text="Commodity">
    <cellValueFactory><CommodityCellValueFactory /></cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

Basically I want to get rid of the cell factories and cell value factories unless I need some formatting to be done on my value.  So I thought I can create a property called

```
String tempCommodityShortName;
String getTempCommodityShortName()
{
    return commodity.commodityShortName();
}
```

in my `Trade` entity and bind this to my table column. But I have around 15 to 20 properties. If I do this in my entity class then it will be bloated with these extra helper method which I don't want to do.

I thought of having a  helper class for every entity like `TradeEntityHelper`/`TradeEntityBusiness`/`TradeEntityAdditions` where I can have all the helper methods and access it in the tableview columns.

My first attempt is instead of class, I choose an interface (since java 8 interface supports default methods)

```
interface ITradeEntityHelper
{
//all helper methods goes here
}

class TradeEntity implements ITradeEntityHelper
{
//real entity methods goes here
}
```

I will bind the interface to my `TableView`.     `TableView<ITradeEntityHelper>` instead of `TableView<TradeEntity>`  Correct me if I am trying something stupid

Now the problem is how do I get my `TradeEntity` reference in my `ITradeEntityHelper` interface so that I can ask

```
tradeEntity.Commodity().commodityShortName().
```

(or) like these

```
interface ITrade{}
class Trade implements ITrade{}
class TradeAdditions implements ITrade{}
```

keep the helper methods in the `Additions` class.

I want to achieve the same for my Controller classes too.

Eg:
Each Controller class in my `Application` should have base interface where I want to have some default java `Predicate`s and java 8 `Function`s defined and want to resue in the controller class.

```
class TradeController implements ITradeController, Initializable
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you, but have a look at [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Also, keep in mind that in Java, as opposed to C# for example, interfaces can have static methods.

Comment: Hey, I knew about default methods and static methods in interface. But my problem is if i implement an interface and write a default method like below. To get the value which i am interested in this case "commodityShortName" i need my trade entity reference in the interface. So that i can say tradeEntity.commodity().commodityShortName(). dats where i am lacking.    default public ExternalComment getCommodityShortName()
 {
  return tradeEntityForWhichINeedCommodityShortName.commodity().commodityShortName();
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can select a value through a multi-level hierarchy using [`Bindings.select`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#select-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.lang.String...-). This allows you to create a single `cellValueFactory` class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class NestedPropertyValueFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>> {

    private final String[] steps;
    private final PropertyValueFactory firstStepSelector;

    /**
     * @param property a string containing the names of the properties seperated
     * by '.'.
     */
    public NestedPropertyValueFactory(@NamedArg("property") String property) {
        String[] properties = property.split("\\.");
        firstStepSelector = new PropertyValueFactory<>(properties[0]);
        this.steps = Arrays.copyOfRange(properties, 1, properties.length);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<T> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T> param) {
        // use PropertyValueFactory for first step and Bindings.select for
        // additonal steps.
        return Bindings.select(firstStepSelector.call(param), steps);
    }

}
```

This class can be used as `cellValueFactory` in the fxml file.

```xml
<cellValueFactory>
    <NestedPropertyValueFactory property="commodity.commodityShortName"/>
</cellValueFactory>
```

Note that if any intermediate step yields `null`, you'll get warnings in `System.err`.

Also with this class you need to use property methods that adhere the naming conventions, i.e. the names of the methods should be `commodityProperty` and `commodityShortNameProperty` in this case (or `getCommodity` and `getCommodityShort` in they are not observable).

Comment: Thanks fabian. Let me try and update you. Between As i asked already, I also want to move all predicates related to particular entity and some convenience methods which i call frequently to a separate interface or to another class which will be equal to my entity class. Any idea? Thanks again for the above answer.